# Move Grub to NVME from old HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, uefi

I have a setup where i use a 500GB NVME drive and a 1TB HDD.
Both have GPT Partitions, but the Grub is installed in HDD alongside windows 10.

I want to move that to the NVME drive so that i am not dependent upon the HDD to boot my system.

**Parted output**

```
shantanu@shantanu-pc:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-08W (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB   315MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      316MB   420MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      420MB   555MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      555MB   210GB   209GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      210GB   524GB   315GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 7      524GB   526GB   2048MB  linux-swap(v1)                                swap
 8      526GB   734GB   208GB   ntfs                                          msftdata
 6      734GB   1000GB  266GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: KINGSTON SA2000M8500G (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  300GB  300GB   ext4
 3      300GB   483GB  183GB   ext4
 2      483GB   500GB  17.2GB  linux-swap(v1)        swap
```

**efi location**

```
shantanu@shantanu-pc:~$ mount | grep boot
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

**what i tried :**

I tried installing grub while pointing to my nvme drive. But it doesn't work cause **/boot/efi** is mounted from **/dev/sda2** as i have shown above

```
shantanu@shantanu-pc:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
shantanu@shantanu-pc:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

i have tried booting with Ubuntu Live USB and tried using **boot-repair** but it does not work and says partition is not **MBR**

I'm kind of stuck here, any guidance would be helpful. And let me know if you want to see any other command outputs. Thanks for reading.

Comment: My pc is kind of old (ASUS M311) but I could not get it to boot off the NVME. I could put / on the NVME, but I had to put /boot and /boot/uefi on a HDD. It probably depends on the UEFI firmware, but there is a chance that it may not be possible on your PC.

Comment: thanks for replying, so nvme boot will only work if partition table is MBR in your machine right ? so gpt+nvme is a unsupported configuration on some motherboards. Is that what you are suggesting ?

Comment: The system I am describing is all GPT disks. So maybe it will work if MBR, I do not know.

Comment: You do not want MBR(msdos). You have to have an ESP - efi system partition on the NVMe drive. Installing grub does not create a partition. Installer in UEFI mode to blank drive will create an ESP, but if drive has partitions, it may depend on which install choice you choose. Some totally erase drive. I always partition all new drives, even larger flash drives, as gpt (since about 2010) and now make ESP as first partition. You have old kernels & then perhaps other cruft. Better to do new install & restore from your backup.